# IIS and MVC show folder structure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

i have tried to deploy an mvc application in an windows server 2008 with iis7.

i have copied all the content to the inetpub/wwwroot folder
i changed the framework version of the application pool to v4.0
i ran the aspnet_regiis.exe

the project was properly released because i have deploy succesfully to my desktop dev (iis) and one arvixe hosting, but i cant make it work on the server.

but i can only see the folder structure, i tried creating virtual directorys and everything, but nothing works. am i missing something.

thx

Comment: Make sure you have full write access to the wwwroot.

Comment: Have you installed MVC on the hosting server?